# \printbibliography results in error: ! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }

Tags: biblatex, biber, input-encodings

I have been dealing with this problem some days. Maybe you can help me? When running `pdflatex` I get this error:

```
! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.15
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
```

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% no recuerdo para que era fancy
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtex.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{klamt1993cosmo} \cite{quantum-continuum-tomasi2005}  \cite{tomasi-PCM1981}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bib file i am using is:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{klamt1993cosmo,
  Title                    = {COSMO: a new approach to dielectric screening in solvents with explicit expressions for the screening energy and its gradient},
  Author                   = {Klamt, Andreas and Sch{\"u}{\"u}rmann, GJGJ},
  Journal                  = {Journal of the Chemical Society, Perkin Transactions 2},
  Year                     = {1993},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {799--805},

  __markedentry            = {},
  Publisher                = {Royal Society of Chemistry}
}

@Article{tomasi-PCM1981,
  Title                    = {Electrostatic interaction of a solute with a continuum. A direct utilizaion of AB initio molecular potentials for the prevision of solvent effects},
  Author                   = {Miertu{\v{s}}, S and Scrocco, E and Tomasi, J},
  Journal                  = {Chemical Physics},
  Year                     = {1981},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {117--129},
  Volume                   = {55},

  Publisher                = {Elsevier}
}

@Article{quantum-continuum-tomasi2005,
  Title                    = {Quantum mechanical continuum solvation models},
  Author                   = {Tomasi, Jacopo and Mennucci, Benedetta and Cammi, Roberto},
  Journal                  = {Chemical reviews},
  Year                     = {2005},
  Number                   = {8},
  Pages                    = {2999--3094},
  Volume                   = {105},

  Publisher                = {ACS Publications}
}
```

I can not change this file, any change I make `jabRef` return them in this way again.

Only for it helps, I have download all packages (texlive, biber 1.9, texmaker) from promt, and I am using Debian.

When I remove `\printbibliography` errors are gone (but I need to print it)

Any idea of what is going on?

**EDIT** i do not know if it is an answer but changing to biblatex it works.

Comment: Works fine for me, but with your old biber installation... Maybe you should install a "vanilla" TeX Live that's up to date.

Comment: @TeXnician ok. Can install it from promt? And, is there any other change i should do?

Comment: @TeXnician Is it not the same if i have installed texlive?Sorry if i am wrong, i am starting with the programme and i get this error

Comment: `biber` 1.9 is very, very old. In TeX Live 2016 and TeX Live 2017 pretest we have currently `biber` 2.7. Last version in TeX Live 2015 was `biber` 2.4. AFAIK `biber` 1.9 is from TeX Live 2014. As I cannot reproduce the problem with TeX Live 2016 or TeX Live 2017 pretest but only with TeX Live 2014, I would recommend to update.

Comment: try to run biber with `biber --output-safechars <file>`

Comment: @Schweinebacke but i do not know why this is the current version of Debian, it is really strange, and anyone has asked the same question..

Comment: Debain/Ubuntu and some other Linux distribution often ship quite old versions of TeX live. You can install vanilla TeX live in order to get proper updates in due time. [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). Your edit confuses me, do you mean changing to BibTeX? Keep in mind that Biber is the preferred backend and BibTeX is only supported for backwards compatibility and only supports a reduced set of features.

Comment: The same question was asked yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example does work using current versions of `biber` and `biblatex`.

The problem with the outdated `biber` `biblatex` combination is, the

```
  Author                   = {Klamt, Andreas and Sch{\"u}{\"u}rmann, GJGJ},
```

line. Using a real UTF8 encoded file does work:

```
\listfiles
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 3.6.
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{klamt1993cosmo,
  Title                    = {COSMO: a new approach to dielectric screening in solvents with explicit expressions for the screening energy and its gradient},
  Author                   = {Klamt, Andreas and Schüürmann, GJGJ},
  Journal                  = {Journal of the Chemical Society, Perkin Transactions 2},
  Year                     = {1993},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {799--805},
  __markedentry            = {},
  Publisher                = {Royal Society of Chemistry}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{klamt1993cosmo}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 spanish.ldf
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
etoolbox.sty    2015/03/19 v2.1d e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    etex.sty    2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 spanish.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
    test.bbl
   ulasy.fd    1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
 ***********
```

and `biber` 1.9 does result in

[image: Bibliography]

without any error.

So I would recommend to either update your TeX distribution (at least `biber` and `biblatex`) or to change your database to use real UTF8 encoded special characters instead of things like `{\"u}`.

BTW:

```
\listfiles
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{klamt1993cosmo,
  Title                    = {COSMO: a new approach to dielectric screening in solvents with explicit expressions for the screening energy and its gradient},
  Author                   = {Klamt, Andreas and Sch\"u\"urmann, GJGJ},
  Journal                  = {Journal of the Chemical Society, Perkin Transactions 2},
  Year                     = {1993},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {799--805},
  __markedentry            = {},
  Publisher                = {Royal Society of Chemistry}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{klamt1993cosmo}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

would also work.

Comment: I have things encoded like that an it does not work

Comment: @HernanProust: Maybe you've forgotten to remove some auxiliary files or you have not fixed the coding of all special characters. I've tested the examples with the given versions of `biber` and `biblatex`. Both work. Have you really tested my examples?