# Unknown compile errors

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is the error that stops the compile

```
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Argument of \UTF@three@octets@noexpand has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.48 \end
         {document}
?
```

When I searched for UTF@three@octets@noexpand I couldn't find anything. When I looked at my bib file I couldn't find anything that could be causing this and the .tex document I'm trying to compile doesn't *seem* to have any major errors in it.
I can't post the actual document but this is the code with the citations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,top=15mm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\author{my name}
\title{document title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textcite{mcgray09}
\textcite{agyeiwaah18}
\textcite{mcgray09}
\parencite{MFAJ17}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I wasn't looking at my bib file well enough, ` and ' both have to be put in {}

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372325/printbibliography-results-in-error-argument-of-utfviiithreeoctets-has-an is related? That is a similar error message caused by `{` and `}` characters in the bibliography file entries.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. It compiles fine now.