# Many Spanish accents in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, babel, accents, spanish, apa7

I'm facing an odd issue. I need to cite a piece with two authors, and both have accents in their surnames (Molina Alarcón and Cerdá y Ferré). Problem is I can add two accents, ó and á, but not the é. Once I do that an error surfaces. Any idea how to solve this issue. As you can see in the MWE, I'm using `{\'{o}}`, `{\'{a}}`, `{\'{a}}` to replace the accented characters in the bib file.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,url=true,backref=bibtex,bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
    andothers = {et al.},
}
\makeatletter \DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish} {\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand} \makeatother 
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{MolinaCerda2012,
author = {Molina Alarc{\'{o}}n, Miguel and Cerd{\'{a}} i Ferr{\'{e}}, Josep},
issn = {1989-8452},
journal = {Arte y Pol{\'{i}}ticas de Identidad},
number = {7},
pages = {11--14},
title = {{Introducci{\'{o}}n. Entre el arte sonoro y el arte de la escucha}},
volume = {7},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
As \textcite{MolinaCerda2012} stated: "quote."
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

EDIT: This is the error I get when compiling:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/spanish-apa.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx))
(./mwe.aux) (./mwe.bbl)
! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30 As \textcite{MolinaCerda2012} 
                                   stated: "quote."
?
```

About my system, I'm using a Mac, OSX is Mojave 10.14.6. My editor is TeXworks 0.6.5 (I cannot upgrade it any more, next one is only compatible with Big Sur and superior ones).

Comment: An excellent MWE, by the way! I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered when I compile your MWE on my system (MacOS 12.2 "Monterey"; MacTeX2021; LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1; and biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16). Do please tell us more about your computing setup, including when you last updated your TeX distribution.

Comment: The MWE compiles fine for me. I get "é" in the output. Please upload the full `.log` file of your LaTeX run to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/ (please use a text-sharing website and not a file-sharing website). That said, while `{\'{e}}` and friends should certainly work, it is usually easier on the eye to write `é` and use `backend=biber,` (which is recommended anyway).

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I'm compiling using pdfLateX > Biber > pdfLateX. I'm loading the bibliography externaly, it only fails when I add the last é to Ferré. If I use é as you suggested, I get the following error: "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:� not set up for use with LaTeX."

Comment: @moewe Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/hqJmyBp8

Comment: Your LaTeX installation is from 2014, it is more than seven years old. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372325/35864 suggests there were issues in TeX live 2014 that would cause the error you are asking about. You should look into updating your TeX live. Note that TeX live is not your editor (TeXworks). If I understand correctly https://tug.org/mactex/ says you can install a current TeX live on Mojave.

Comment: @moewe Updated my TeX Live to the 2021 version and solved the issue. Thanks for the recommendation.